# Inequation with 2 variables - how to proceed?

Tags: quadratics

> Find the highest value of $K$ such that
>   $$x^2 - 10x + 40 \ge K$$
>   $ \forall  x \in R$.

Step 1: I'll assume $K$ is equal to $0$ just to make it simpler (Is it OK to do so?)
$$x^2 - 10x + 40 \ge 0$$

Step 2:  Solving this with the quadratic equation formula:

$$ x = \frac{-(-10) \pm \sqrt[2]{100 - (4)(1)(40)}}{2(1)}$$

Step 3: How to proceed with the negative square root?

$$x = \frac{-(-10) \pm \sqrt[2]{-60}}{2(1)}$$

Possible answers:

$a) 4$  $b) 5$  $c) 6$

$d) 7$  $e) 8$

Comment: **Hint:** How can you determine that a quadratic equation has no solutions? Use this on the quadratic equation $x^2−10x+40-K = 0$. What can you say now?

Comment: You're minimizing the quadratic, so find the vertex

Comment: @imranfat, doble check, find the greatest value.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
We have that
$$x^2-10x = (x-5)^2 - 25. $$
Can you see why? It is due to [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). Hence we have that

$$\color{blue}{x^2-10x}+40 = \color{blue}{(x-5)^2 -25} + 40 = (x-5)^2+15. $$

Now recall that the square of a real number cannot be less than $0$. How can you use this?

Comment: So the max reduction, is like you say, $(x - 5)^2 + 14 \ge K$  I could try to guess a number to satisfy this, but the $K$ confuses me.

Comment: I tried to guide you to find the $K$ with my hint :-). Since a real square can be $0$ - but not less - we have that $(x-5)^2\geq 0$, hence $(x-5)^2 +15 \geq 0 + 15 = 15.$ Therefore the correct answer is $\fbox{K = 15}$. By the way, as some extra info for the curious person, this also reveals that the left hand side achieves its minimum when $(x-5)^2 = 0$, i.e. when $ x = 5$.

Comment: I see, thanks. So $ 15 \ge K$. But the answer is the lowest value of $k$ is $15$ and the maximus is: $infinity +$?

Comment: No, $K = 15$ is the *highest* possible value that satisfies $x^2-10x+40 \geq K$ for all real $x$. There are many, infact an infinite number of, lower values that satisfy the inequality because
$$(x-5)^2+15\geq 15 \geq 10 \geq 0 \geq -1000 \geq ... $$
et cetera, et cetera.

Comment: thanks, I follow your logic, but $15$ is not one of the possible answers. Please, see update.

Comment: @user3352567 Then there is a mistake in the exercise. The correct answer is $K = 15$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Think about the graph of $f(x) = x^2−10x+40$.  Does it attain a minimum value?  Can you figure out where?

Comment: @imranfat He's looking for the highest value of a number which is always lower than or equal to the quadratic.  I.e. the minimum.

Comment: @imranfat Yes, but the highest value of K is the first integer below the minimum of the function

Comment: ok, makes sense

Comment: @Bye_World, I don't know about graphs and functions. This is an exercise for my sister that is in 4 grade high school. Please, explain a little bit more.

Comment: I don't mean any offense but if you don't know what a function is or how to graph one, I think you might not have the skills to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$x^2 - 10x + 40 \ge K$$

which means the term on the left serves as an upper bound for $K$. To find the biggest value for $K$ is the same as finding the smallest value of that bound.

Minimum via derivative

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2 - 10x + 40\right) = 0 = 2x-10$$

As it is a simple parabola, I omit the proof that it is a minimum (and not a maximum) Please comment if you need help with that.

The term has a minimum at $x=5$, inserting that into the original formula yields
$$5^2 - 10\cdot 5 + 40 \ge K$$
which gives
$$15 \ge K$$

15 is the highest value of $K$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: here is a way of doing a similar question.

$$4y^2-36y+100\ge K$$

We **complete the square** to obtain $$(2y-9)^2+19\ge K$$

And we know that squares are always greater than or equal to zero.

Where does the $19$ come from. Well $$19=100-9^2$$ and we can also compute $$b^2-4ac=36^2-4\times 4\times 100=-304=-16\times 19=(2a)^2\times 19$$ so that $\sqrt {b^2-4ac}=4\sqrt{-19}=2a\sqrt {-19}$ and using the quadratic formula to find the roots will cancel the factor $2a$. Notice that $36^2-4\times 4 \times 100=16\times (9^2-100)$. This is not a coincidence.

The negative number under the square root (the negative **discriminant** $b^2-4ac$) indicates that there are no real roots to the quadratic, so it always stays positive (or negative - this one is positive), and $K\gt 0$.

So the answer is related to the method you tried to use, and if you carry it through algebraically you can explore how it all fits together for yourself. I find that completing the square directly is often the easiest way to solve questions like this without making mistakes.